# How can i run Single PHP File using apache-tomcat-6.0.18?

Tags: php, apache, gwt

i want to run single php file using apache-tomcat-6.0.18

my project is GWT project with server side is java servlet

i deployed my project on server in apache-tomcat-6.0.18/webapps/ folder

So please tell me the solution to run php file

Comment: Tomcat is designed for running servlets, which handle their own responses to HTTP requests. PHP is designed as a preprocessor that runs in tandem with a full-blown webserver like Apache, which handles the requests itself.

Comment: Agree with Dav. You are mixing things up. Its possible to run PHP from within java (as explained in a post below), but you want to stay away from it. Either run java servlets, or completely run PHP as explained in http://code.google.com/p/gwtphp/ if you absolutely want GWT as well. But don't mix technologies, its not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this by using **JavaBridge**..

Download below jar file  (ie extract jars from JavaBridge.war)

```
JavaBridge.jar
php-script.jar
php-servlet.jar
```

and put into your project lib folder. then type the following entry in web.xml

**web.xml**

```
<!-- the following 8 lines extend the servlet spec 2.2 "url-pattern" to handle PHP PATH_INFO: *.php/something?what=that. Remove them, if you don't need this feature. -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- the following adds the JSR223 listener. Remove it if you don't want to use the JSR223 API -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- the back end for external (console, Apache/IIS-) PHP scripts; remove it if you don't need this -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- runs PHP scripts in this web app; remove it if you don't need this -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

save the file. Restart tomcat server. now Php files will be work under tomcat server!

Answer (score 2):

"www" folder is present in IIS server not in apache ...
In apache tomcat server instead of "www" , "Root" folder is present 
copy all those needed files in that root folder  and have acces to thos files

after installation of any server a single restart is mandatory ,, otherwise results are unpredictable...
                          Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

[Use the PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/). As long as your PHP was compiled with cgi support, it should work seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

[Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) has a war that allows to run PHP scripts in apache tomcat or glassfish. For a step by step guide look at [this](http://www.studytrails.com/blog/php-on-a-java-app-server-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/) article

Answer (score -1):

You should put your php file in `www` folder in apache installation and then you can access that file from browser like this:

```
http://localhost/your_file_name.php
```

`localhost` is the default host name in most configurations.

Comment: but there no folder like www in apache-tomcat-6.0.18 installation directory

Comment: what about what like 'httdocs' or `public_html`, you need to search in for those names in apache directory.

Comment: "Apache Tomcat" is not the same thing as "Apache". One is a servlet host, the other is a web server.

Comment: i am using Apache Tomacat and there is no folder with name httdocs & public_html .
it contains only bin,conf,logs,webapps,lib,work folders